# Is there a way how to run madvoc inside of spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jodd

Is there a way to run [Madvoc](http://jodd.org/doc/madvoc/) web microframework inside of Spring Boot?

Spring Boot allows integration of other technologies (we experimented with Apache Wicket running under Spring Boot).

Is this possible for [JODD madvoc](http://jodd.org/doc/madvoc/)? Is there any proper configuration example?

**EDIT #1**
I tried to add Spring Boot servlet filter configuration for Madvoc, but can't see Madvoc init output like this one:

```
INFO jodd.madvoc.Madvoc - Madvoc starting... 
INFO jodd.madvoc.Madvoc - Default Madvoc web application created.
```

This is how my init code looks like ...

```
@Configuration
public class MadvocInitializer implements ServletContextInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        FilterRegistration filter = sc.addFilter("madvoc", MadvocServletFilter.class);
        filter.setInitParameter("madvoc.webapp","app.web.jodd.AppWebApplication");

        EnumSet NON_ASYNC_DISPATCHER_TYPES =
                EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE,DispatcherType.REQUEST);

        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(NON_ASYNC_DISPATCHER_TYPES, true, "/jodd/*");

        System.out.println("+++ MADVOC FILTER");
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2**
Filter configuration references 'AppWebApplication' which looks like below. I can see print message from 'registerMadvocComponents' code, so something is definitely running.

```
public class AppWebApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    public void registerMadvocComponents() {
        super.registerMadvocComponents();

        System.out.println("+++ MADVOC FILTER - configuration");

        registerComponent(MadvocConfig.class);
       // registerComponent(MyRewriter.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you verify if `onStartup` gets called?

Comment: Yes its called, I can see print message "+++ MADVOC FILTER" on console.

Comment: Cool, then I can try it without SpringBoot, because its servlets3 :)

Comment: See my latest post edit above for some further details ...

Comment: Whats more having Spring Bean injection would be amazing !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in the nutshell here we have Servlets 3.x way of registering Madvoc filter that is going to register everything.

Please check working example with Servlets 3 [here](https://github.com/oblac/jodd-quickstart/tree/master/madvoc2).

Your code looks fine, but here is what you can check:

1. Maybe Springboot simply hides the logs from Jodd and you are not seeing it is working.
2. There might be a problem if you filter to `/jodd/*`:) By default, actions will be mapped to e.g. `/index.html` instead of `/jodd/index.html`. Hence, you will not be able to run actions. To test this, please map filter to root (`/*`) and see if you can reach your Madvoc actions now :)

To inject Spring into the Madvoc actions - check class `PetiteMadvocController`. This one injects `Petite` beans in the madvoc (yeah, who needs Spring anyway:). Basically, you just need to create action class in the Springs application context.

Comment: Setting LoggerFactory.setLoggerFactory(new SimpleLoggerFactory(Logger.Level.DEBUG)); did the trick and I can see log info during SpringBoot start up. great. Seems like its been /jodd/* issue I fixed this, still having some isee, but get back with update. Regarding the Spring beans .. reason is simple, we have a few we use in app already ...

Comment: Glad it worked ;) Sure, no problem, just keep rocking ;)